# NodeJS HTTP Requests Promises and Storing Results in Variables

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm building a front-end application that makes HTTP requests to 2 separate API's.

```
http://greetings_api:3000/getGreeting
  data {'language': 'es'}
Response: 'Hola'

http://users_api:3000/getUser
  data {'userid': 1}
Response: 'Jose Smith'
```

I have a single route that makes a request to these API's and then returns those responses:

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request-promise');

var greetingOptions = {
    uri: 'http://greetings_api:3000/getGreeting',
    hostname: 'greetings_api',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'language': 'es'
    }
};

var greeting = {
    getGreeting: function() {
        return request(greetingOptions);
    }
}

function myGreeting() {
    return greeting.getGreeting();
};

var userOptions = {
    uri: 'http://users_api:3000/getUser',
    hostname: 'users_api',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'id': 1
    }
};

var user = {
    getUser: function() {
        return request(userOptions);
    }
}

function myUser() {
    return user.getUser();
};

function getWelcome(req, res) {

    // How do you store this....
    myUser().then(function(result) {
        console.log('result')
        return result;
    })

    // ...and this...
    myGreeting().then(function(result) {
      console.log('Greet ' + result);
        return result;
    });

    /// ...and then send them with this?
    res.send(greeting + ' ' + user);
}

module.exports = { getWelcome };
```

So with the current code I get the correct output in the console. The problem is that I need to be able to send the response from the route with the combination of both API responses. What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the response before the promises resolving.

with [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) we can write asynchronous code that looks and behaves like synchronous.

```
async function getWelcome(req, res) {
  // we can wrap our operation in a try/catch block to handle
  // both asynchronous and synchronous errors
  try {
    // with the await keyword we can wait for all promises to resolve
    // before we continue with our code

    /* if one of the promises inside Promise.all rejects we move to the catch block */
    const [user, greeting] = await Promise.all([
      myUser(),
      myGreeting()
    ]);
    // send the response if no errors
    res.send(greeting + ' ' + user);
    catch(e) {
      res.status(404).send();
    }
}
```

Comment: While I also like await/async, the comment about the messiness of nested then() callbacks is a little disingenuous, since you could have used Promise.all() as the other answer shows.

Comment: @Paul I've stated that if you have `multiple promises that depends on each other it can get pretty messy`. I wasn't talking specific on this problem but just a tip in general because it looks like the OP is not used to promises.

Comment: why are you nesting promises in your first code? that would be the *wrong* way to chain those promises - the correct way would be `promise1()
.then(p1 => promise2(p1))
.then(p2 => promise3(p2))
.then(p3 => { res.send(p3); })
.catch(err => console.log(err));`

Comment: @Bravo We dont need to return `res.send` we just need to call it.. Thats why we don't need to return this Promises, We still have access to the data returned by the previous Promises

Comment: that's irrelevant - but I've made it so it's not returned ... and still no nested promises

Comment: You right if we just return it we can omit the body and just chain `then`s.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make 2 parallel requests and send response after completing both. Here [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function can help you.

```
Promise.all([myUser(), myGreeting()]).then(function(result) {
    // result[0] - user
    // result[1] - greeting
    res.send(result[0] + ' ' + result[1]);
});
```